# React JS Callback Functions removing list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, callback

In the code below, the `removeTask` function is passing `id`. It's working fine. Instead of passing a id as a parameter, can I declare the id as a variable like `let myId = id` and then pass `myID` as a parameter in the `removeTask` function? Like:

```
const removeTask = (myID ) => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter(task => task.myID !== myID))
}
```

If I do it like that it doesn't work. Can anyone help me out with the difference?

```
const TaskListContextProvider = props => {
   const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
     {name: "Faruk", id:1},
     {name: "Ramesh", id:2},
     {name: "Sugana", id:3}
   ])

   const addTask = tit => {
     setTasks([...tasks, {name:tit, id:uuid()}])
   }

   const removeTask = (id) => {
     setTasks(tasks.filter(task => task.id !== id))
   }
```

Comment: The difference is that the name of the parameter is up to you. So you can call it `(id)`, or `(myID)`, or `(QuarterPounderWithCheese)`. But when you're filtering through your tasks array, those objects are already defined. For example, the first item in the initial state is `{name: "Faruk", id:1},`, the key there is `id`, so that's the one you have to use. You can change the parameter, but you have to match the key name for the data, so it'd be something like `setTasks(tasks.filter(task => task.id!== myID ))`

Comment: ok. task.id checks the object id. what about myID. Am not getting myID.